# How does ORB combine BRIEF descriptors over pyramid levels?

Tags: computer-vision

The [paper](http://www.gwylab.com/download/ORB_2012.pdf) briefly mentions using pyramids for getting scale invariance with oFAST and even has a line which says they use pyramids for making the BRIEF descriptors scale invariant. For the former, non-maximum suppression is used to combine across pyramid levels. But for the latter, I couldn't find any explanation of how you would combine them. Say you find BRIEF descriptors in the same location over several pyramid levels. How do you combine them? Or do you just keep all of them as separate descriptors?